# Sending JSON to Slack in a HTTP POST request

Tags: json, api, slack-api

I'm trying to send a message using [Slack's chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) API call. I have no problems encoding my test messages within HTTP GET, but I'm trying to achieve the same result with JSON in a HTTP POST request.

I've been testing with both `curl` and [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), but Slack doesn't seem to be acknowledging my request body at all.

```
{
  "ok": false,
  "error": "not_authed"
}
```

In `curl`, my request is encoded like this:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"token":"my-token-here","channel":"#channel-name-or-id","text":"Text here.","username":"otherusername"}'
```

In Postman, this is the raw body:

```
{
    "token":"my-token-here",
    "channel":"#channel-name-or-id",
    "text":"Text here.",
    "username":"otherusername"
}
```

I haven't done anything like this before, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something out. Thanks!

Answer (score 68):

I'm a bit late, but I hope this can help other people who stumble into this issue like me. I've just been in touch with Slack, and this is what they told me:

> The Slack Web API doesn't accept JSON data at all — so along with changing the Content-Type those variables should be posted using standard HTTP form attributes.
>
> We plan to support JSON data in the future for consistency in the future.

So, your cURL line should look like:

```
curl -X POST -d 'token=my-token-here&channel=#channel-name-or-id&text=Text here.&username=otherusername'`
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: I love how they actually never really spell this out in the documentation but then give every example in JSON as if a web developer is going to look at it and think, of course I'm going to form encode my JSON object and plug it on a query string. That just makes perfect sense.

Comment: This is so annoying. Some api calls even support sending curl -d 'payload={"json":"wtf"}'. The docs are way too ambiguous about this.

Comment: This is just crazy all those Json examples and the api doesn't actualy take a Json object at all.  They even have a message builder where you can build complex messages in Json but then in reality you have to carve the Json up into a querystring to make it really work.

Comment: So it doesn't take JSON, but it responds with JSON.... that makes no sense!

Comment: The documentation over at github is is also half json, half markdown

Comment: this is so stupid and i'll never get back the 3 hours of my life i wasted on this

Answer (score 12):

Okay, after re-reading the documentation I found it:

> JSON-encoded bodies
>
> For these write methods, you may alternatively send your HTTP POST
>   data as Content-type: application/json.
>
> There are some ground rules:
>
> - You must explicitly set the Content-type HTTP header to application/json. We won't interpret your POST body as such without it.
> - You must transmit your token as a bearer token in the Authorization HTTP header.
> - You cannot send your token as part of the query string or as an attribute in your posted JSON.
> - Do not mix arguments between query string, URL-encoded POST body, and JSON attributes. Choose one approach per request.
> - Providing an explicitly null value for an attribute will result in whichever default behavior is assigned to it.

And the `curl` example. Notice the **Authorization** header.

```
curl -X POST \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer xoxb-1234-56789abcdefghijklmnop' \
     -H 'Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
    --data '{"channel":"C061EG9SL","text":""..."}' \
https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the Authorization header.

Comment: it is NOWHERE said, but absolutely required, to ALSO include the charset:

  -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \

Answer (score 6):

This may not qualify for the complete answer, but if the purpose is to send a message attachment, you can send a `urlencode`d JSON structure as the value of the `attachments` parameter, like so (split into multiple lines for clarity):

```
https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?
token=YOUR-TOKE-N000&
channel=%23alerts&
text=Hi&
attachments=%5B%7B%22color%22%3A%22good%22%2C%22fallback%22%3A%22plain+text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22colored+text%22%7D%5D
```

The value of `attachments` is URL-encoded `[{"color":"good","fallback":"plain text","text":"colored text"}]`. You should be able to use all attachment attributes [described here](https://api.slack.com/docs/attachments).

Answer (score 6):

As of **March 2018**, **Slack** now supports **POST** with **JSON** body

**Endpoint**: `https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage`

**Headers**: `Authorization: Bearer xoxp-your-hardly-find-token-here`

**Body**: `{"channel":"CH9NN37","text":"something from me!"}`

*Notice the* **Bearer** *in the* **Authorization** *header.*

Comment: I've been using this API since **november 2017** - I wrote this answer to this very question on January 9: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178295/1428679 - and as far as I can see, your example is exactly the same. Am I missing something, or was there some documentation kerfuffle?

Answer (score 5):

Slack has been updated, this now works. Try this example:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one."}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/AAAAAA/BBBBBB/CCCCCC
```

See https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks for documentation.

Comment: This doesn't (yet) appear to work for the generic web API; only for (incoming) webhooks (which, I think, don't even need authentication via a token, as in the question's example).

Comment: This limited example works as is. We use it in production.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting each property in its own -d parameter, like so:

```
curl https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage -X POST -d "channel=#tehchannel" -d "text=teh text" -d "username=teh user" -d "token=teh-token-you-got-from-teh-page-that-machinehead115-linked-to" -d "icon_emoji=:simple_smile:"
```

Answer (score 2):

On postman you can frame your request like this:

url(POST) : https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage

Then under `Headers` section put these two headers:

1. key(`Content-Type`) value(`application/json`)
2. key(`Authorization`) value(`YOUR-TOKEN-NAME`)

Then in `Body` section in `raw` form put your data:

```
    {"channel": "CHANNEL-NAME", "data": "You better post this to channel"}
```

Comment: Just use "text" instead of "data" in the body section

Answer (score 1):

`not_authed` means *No authentication token provided.*

Which token are you passing along in the request? You need to pass your OAuth token, which you can get from [here](https://api.slack.com/web).

Comment: I've managed to pass my token along in a GET request, and in a POST form-body. (Those return `channel_not_found` instead.) I suspect Slack just isn't accepting JSON in a POST body.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in powershell and it works like a charm.

```
$url="https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"
    $messageContent= # your message here
    $token = # your token here
    $channel = # channel name
    $opt_username= # optional user name

    $body = @{token=$token;channel=$channel;username=$opt_username;text=$messageContent;pretty=1}

    try
    {
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Body $body
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
        Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java and spring such dependency, Voila!! here you go

```
     * Make a POST call to the chat.PostMessage.
     */
    public void chatPostMessage(Message message)
    {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.add("token", slackPostMessageToken); //Required
        map.add("text", message.getText());//Required
        map.add("channel", message.getChannelId());//Required

        map.add("unfurl_links","true");
        map.add("as_user","false");//Default false
        map.add("icon_emoji",":chart_with_upwards_trend:");
        map.add("attachments","[\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"fallback\": \"Required plain-text summary of the attachment.\",\n" +
                "            \"color\": \"#36a64f\",\n" +
                "            \"pretext\": \"Optional text that appears above the attachment block\",\n" +
                "            \"author_name\": \"Bobby Tables\",\n" +
                "            \"author_link\": \"http://flickr.com/bobby/\",\n" +
                "            \"author_icon\": \"http://flickr.com/icons/bobby.jpg\",\n" +
                "            \"title\": \"Slack API Documentation\",\n" +
                "            \"title_link\": \"https://api.slack.com/\",\n" +
                "            \"text\": \"Optional text that appears within the attachment\",\n" +
                "            \"fields\": [\n" +
                "                {\n" +
                "                    \"title\": \"Priority\",\n" +
                "                    \"value\": \"High\",\n" +
                "                    \"short\": false\n" +
                "                }\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            \"image_url\": \"http://my-website.com/path/to/image.jpg\",\n" +
                "            \"thumb_url\": \"http://example.com/path/to/thumb.png\",\n" +
                "            \"footer\": \"Datoo ©\",\n" +
                "            \"ts\": "+System.currentTimeMillis()+"" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]");
        map.add("username","III");


        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(slackPostMessageUrl, request, String.class);
            System.out.println(response);
        }
        catch (RestClientException e) {
            logger.error("Error :-( : ", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This helped me... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Below curl command worked for me.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer xoxb-41234078565-14457098702432-ZLJj9UFOZKnOJtjNW4dv3ukG'  -H 'Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'  --data '{"channel":"#general","text":"I hope the tour went well, Mr. Wonka."}' https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage
```